# SharePoint 2010 Profile Enhancements

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, managed-metadata

I am looking for any 3rd party tools that would enhance the useability, functionality, as well as the branding of the SharePoint 2010 MySites.

Currently we would like a more intuitive user interface with maybe some added functionality, but i am having a difficult time finding any COTS tools to use.

Answer (score 2):

Check out NewsGator Social Sites.

http://www.newsgator.com/products/social-sites-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

It's like Facebook + Twitter for SharePoint.